# Tensorflow CNN image augmentation pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to learn the new Tensorflow APIs and I am a bit lost on where to get a handle on my input batch tensors so I can manipulate and augment them with for example tf.image.

This is the my current network & pipeline:

```
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = read_data()
# trainX [num_image, height, width, channels], these are numpy arrays

#...
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testX, testY))

#...
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, 
                 train_dataset.output_shapes)
features, labels = iterator.get_next()
train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
test_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(test_dataset)

#...defining cnn architecture...

# In the train loop
TrainLoop {
   sess.run(train_init_op)  # switching to train data
   sess.run(train_step, ...) # running a train step

   #... 
   sess.run(test_init_op)  # switching to test data
   test_loss = sess.run(loss, ...) # printing test loss after epoch
}
```

I'm using the Dataset API creating 2 datasets so that in the trainloop I can calculate the train and test loss and log them.

Where in this pipeline would I manipulate and distort my input batch of images?
I'm not creating any tf.placeholders for my trainX input batches so I can't manipulate them with tf.image because for example `tf.image.flip_up_down` requires a 3-D or 4-D tensor.

- What is the natural way to implement this pipeline with the new API?
- Is there a module or easy way to augment an input batch of images for training that would fit in this pipeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a really good [article](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance) and [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIcqeP7MFH0) released recently that go over the API in a lot more detail than my response here. Here's a brief example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def read_data():
    n_train = 100
    n_test = 50
    height = 20
    width = 30
    channels = 3
    trainX = (np.random.random(
        size=(n_train, height, width, channels)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    testX = (np.random.random(
            size=(n_test, height, width, channels))*255).astype(np.uint8)
    trainY = (np.random.random(size=(n_train,))*10).astype(np.int32)
    testY = (np.random.random(size=(n_test,))*10).astype(np.int32)
    return trainX, testX, trainY, testY


trainX, testX, trainY, testY = read_data()
# trainX [num_image, height, width, channels], these are numpy arrays


train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trainX, trainY))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((testX, testY))


def map_single(x, y):
    print('Map single:')
    print('x shape: %s' % str(x.shape))
    print('y shape: %s' % str(y.shape))
    x = tf.image.per_image_standardization(x)
    # Consider: x = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(x)
    return x, y


def map_batch(x, y):
    print('Map batch:')
    print('x shape: %s' % str(x.shape))
    print('y shape: %s' % str(y.shape))
    # Note: this flips ALL images left to right. Not sure this is what you want
    # UPDATE: looks like tf documentation is wrong and you need a 3D tensor?
    # return tf.image.flip_left_right(x), y
    return x, y


batch_size = 32
train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat().shuffle(100)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(map_single, num_parallel_calls=8)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(map_batch)
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(2)

test_dataset = test_dataset.map(
        map_single, num_parallel_calls=8).batch(batch_size).map(map_batch)
test_dataset = test_dataset.prefetch(2)


iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, 
                 train_dataset.output_shapes)
features, labels = iterator.get_next()
train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
test_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(test_dataset)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_init_op)
    feat, lab = sess.run((features, labels))

    print(feat.shape)
    print(lab.shape)

    sess.run(test_init_op)
    feat, lab = sess.run((features, labels))

    print(feat.shape)
    print(lab.shape)
```

A few notes:

1. This approach relies on being able to load your entire dataset into memory. If you cannot, consider using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`. This can lead to slow shuffle times if your shuffle buffer is large. My preferred method is to load some `keys` tensor entirely into memory - it might just be the indices of each example - then `map` that key value to data values using `tf.py_func`. This is slightly less efficient than converting to `tfrecords`, but with `prefetching` it likely won't affect performance. Since the shuffling is done before the mapping, you only have to load `shuffle_buffer` keys into memory, rather than `shuffle_buffer` examples.
2. To augment your dataset, use `tf.data.Dataset.map` either before or after the batch operation, depending on whether or not you want to apply a batch-wise operation (something working on a 4D image tensor) or element-wise operation (3D image tensor). Note it looks like the documentation for `tf.image.flip_left_right` is out of date, since I get an error when I try and use a 4D tensor. If you want to augment you data randomly, use `tf.image.random_flip_left_right` rather than `tf.image.flip_left_right`.
3. If you're using a `tf.estimator.Estimator` (or wouldn't mind converting your code to using it), then check out [`tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) for an in-built way of switching between datasets.
4. Consider shuffling/repeating your dataset with the `shuffle`/`repeat` methods. See [the article](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance) for notes on efficiencies. In particular, repeat -> shuffle -> map -> batch -> batch-wise map -> prefetch seems to be the best ordering of operations for most applications.

Comment: Great ressources and explanations. I managed to implement your suggestions on shuffle, repeat and batch and it is working fine. But image augmentation I am still struggling. If I call `tf.data.Dataset.map` before OR after `dataset.batch()` it always gives me a 4-D tensor to work with (contradiction to your 2. point). Is this 4-D tensor the batch of images or the whole dataset? Is this the point where I use the `dataset.map` and then use batch image transformations like `tf.image.random_flip_left_right`?

Comment: edited. Added example, and point 1 changed significantly - you have it right if you can load your whole dataset into memory. I also really like this way of switching between datasets now - didn't realize you could do this with iterators :).

Comment: Thanks for these additions. I was actually running into memory issues like you said and I haven't quite figured out how to do it with generators. I've implemented another solution by creating 2 `initializiable iterators` via the `dataset.make_initializable_iterator()`. Here I've uploaded my model: https://github.com/toemm/TF-CNN-regression/blob/master/BA-CNN_so.ipynb (Cell [7])
Is this viable? I'm running into some issues that may be related to this not working properly but it is hard to debug.

Comment: What's your image source? If you have a bunch of files on disk (or in a zip file) you can make a dataset of just their filenames, shuffle/repeat these, then load them in a map call. Alternatively you could convert them to tfrecords. That's supposedly faster, but it will take up a chunk of additinal memory, they're hard to debug and I've never noticed a speed difference so long as you're using pretetch and your entire process is GPU constrained.

Comment: For anyone visiting in future, flip LR is working with 3D and 4D tensors